execute immediate to create view
I am trying to create a view using the execute immediate statement, and it seems some people have succeded, but it appears I can't do the same.
I am currently working on sqlplus, here is the code :
create or replace procedure viewing_mythology( mythologie VARCHAR2, id NUMBER ) as

sql_cmd VARCHAR2(500);

name_view    VARCHAR2(30) := (mythology || '_ENTITY_VIEW');
--other variable

BEGIN

sql_cmd := 'create or replace view ' || name_view || ' as
select nom_entite, race, symbole, portrait, nom_mention, auteur_mention, date_mention, type_mention
From Entites Natural Join Symboliques Natural Join Mentions Natural Join Localisations 
where Localisations.nom_mythologie = ''' || mythologie || ''' ;';

dbms_output.put_line(sql_cmd);
execute immediate sql_cmd;

--SOME OTHER CODE

END;
/

And I am getting this output in the terminal :
create or replace view grecque_ENTITY_VIEW as
select nom_entite, race, symbole,
portrait, nom_mention, auteur_mention, date_mention, type_mention
From Entites
Natural Join Symboliques Natural Join Mentions Natural Join Localisations
where
Localisations.nom_mythologie = 'grecque' ;
BEGIN viewing_mythology('grecque', 1); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00911: invalid character
ORA-06512: at "L3_23.VIEWING_MYTHOLOGY", line 20
ORA-06512: at line 1

I tried to remove the string concatenation, I executed it without the "where" statement, I also tried with a much simpler view and it didn't work.
Also, the result of the dbms_output command gives me a correct command for the creation of my view, and when I copy and paste it on the sqlplus terminal it works perfectly fine.
Is it just slqplus that refuses this kind of execution ?
PROBLEM SOLVED
So, first of two things, don't put semicolon at the end of a varchar you want to pass into an "execute immediate" (1) UNLESS you are creating a trigger (2), then you can put a semicolon, but no slash, yeah, kinda confusing.
Remember it is weird to create a view or trigger via a procedure (I think, that is what most people told me) but it really depends on your data model from what I understood.
And use authid current_user in the signature of your procedure (3), in order to let oracle know "which privileges it have access to".

What is the error message you're getting? You can add it to the question.

Thanks, I just added the error I get everytime.

Check out this question. Wondering if some of the semicolons are unexpected? In fact, the second last semicolon in this line may be the culprit || mythologie || ''' ;';

So, I removed the semicolon, however I now get an error ORA-01031: insufficient privileges but I created the table on which I am trying to create a view, so shouldn't I have all the privileges ?

It's most likely execute immediate that you lack the privileges for. This post seems relevant.

Thank you very much, it all works fine now !
